# Keep Getting this Error: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 241 pos 10: 'data != null'

Tags: flutter, dart

Sorry for the large amount of code! I just started with flutter and am very new to programming as a whole. I am trying to make a functioning submittable form and followed a tutorial to do so, but I keep getting this error when I try to load the form page:

'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 241 pos 10: 'data != null'

I have attached the code, but if this is the wrong bit of code for the error let me know and I can attach the other lib files. When it works, I want this to be submittable form to a URL I have and JSON encoded. 
I greatly appreciate any help!

I have tried removing all validation, and I have tried looking through the "null(s)", but am unsure which one one is throwing the error.

```
class MyFormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyFormPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _FormPage createState() => new _FormPage();
}

class _FormPage extends State<MyFormPage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new 
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  Contact newContact = new Contact();
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<String> _information = <String>[
    '',
    'male',
    'female',
  ];
  String _info = '';

  final TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();
  Future _chooseDate(BuildContext context, String initialDateString) async {
    var now = new DateTime.now();
    var initialDate = convertToDate(initialDateString) ?? now;
    initialDate = (initialDate.year >= 1900 && initialDate.isBefore(now)
        ? initialDate
        : now);

    var result = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: initialDate,
        firstDate: new DateTime(1900),
        lastDate: new DateTime.now());

    if (result == null) return;

    setState(() {
      _controller.text = new DateFormat.yMd().format(result);
    });
  }

  DateTime convertToDate(String input) {
    try {
      var d = new DateFormat.yMd().parseStrict(input);
      return d;
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new SafeArea(
          top: false,
          bottom: false,
          child: new Form(
              key: _formKey,
              autovalidate: true,
              child: new ListView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                children: <Widget>[
                  new TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                      hintText: 'Enter your first name',
                  labelText: 'First Name',
                ),
                inputFormatters: [new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(15)],
                validator: (val) =>
                    val.isEmpty ? 'First name is required' : null,
                onSaved: (val) => newContact.firstName = val,
              ),
              new TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                  hintText: 'Enter your last name',
                  labelText: 'Last Name',
                ),
                inputFormatters: [new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(15)],
                validator: (val) =>
                    val.isEmpty ? 'Last name is required' : null,
                onSaved: (val) => newContact.lastName = val,
              ),
              new Row(children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                    child: new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                    hintText: 'Enter your date of birth',
                    labelText: 'D.O.B.',
                  ),
                  controller: _controller,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                  onSaved: (val) => newContact.dob = convertToDate(val),
                )),
                new IconButton(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
                  tooltip: 'Choose date',
                  onPressed: (() {
                    _chooseDate(context, _controller.text);
                  }),
                )
              ]),
              new TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.phone),
                  hintText: 'Enter a phone number',
                  labelText: 'Phone',
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                inputFormatters: [
                  new WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(
                      new RegExp(r'^[()\d -]{1,15}$')),
                ],
                validator: (value) => isValidPhoneNumber(value)
                    ? null
                    : 'Phone number must be entered as (###)###-####',
                onSaved: (val) => newContact.phone = val,
              ),
              new TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.email),
                  hintText: 'Enter a email address',
                  labelText: 'Email',
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                validator: (value) => isValidEmail(value)
                    ? null
                    : 'Please enter a valid email address',
                onSaved: (val) => newContact.email = val,
              ),
              new FormField(
                builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
                  return InputDecorator(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.group),
                      labelText: 'Gender',
                      errorText: state.hasError ? state.errorText : null,
                    ),
                    isEmpty: _info == '',
                    child: new DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                      child: new DropdownButton<String>(
                        value: _info,
                        isDense: true,
                        onChanged: (String newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            newContact.gender = newValue;
                            _info = newValue;
                            state.didChange(newValue);
                          });
                        },
                        items: _information.map((String value) {
                          return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: value,
                            child: new Text(value),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                validator: (val) {
                  return val != '' ? null : 'Please select a gender';
                },
              ),
              new Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, top: 20.0),
                  child: new RaisedButton(
                    child: const Text('Submit'),
                    onPressed: _submitForm,
                  )),
            ],
          ))),
    );
  }

  bool isValidPhoneNumber(String input) {
    final RegExp regex = new RegExp(r'^\(\d\d\d\)\d\d\d\-\d\d\d\d$');
    return regex.hasMatch(input);
  }

 bool isValidEmail(String input) {
    final RegExp regex = new RegExp(
        r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,253}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,253}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$");
    return regex.hasMatch(input);
  }

  bool isValidDob(String dob) {
    if (dob.isEmpty) return true;
    var d = convertToDate(dob);
    return d != null && d.isBefore(new DateTime.now());
  }

  void showMessage(String message, [MaterialColor color = Colors.red]) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
        new SnackBar(backgroundColor: color, content: new Text(message)));
  }

  void _submitForm() {
    final FormState form = _formKey.currentState;

    if (!form.validate()) {
      showMessage('Form is not valid!  Please review and correct.');
    } else {
      form.save(); //This invokes each onSaved event

      print('Form save called, newContact is now up to date...');
      print('First Name: ${newContact.firstName}');
      print('Last Name: ${newContact.lastName}');
      print('Dob: ${newContact.dob}');
      print('Phone: ${newContact.phone}');
      print('Email: ${newContact.email}');
      print('Gender: ${newContact.gender}');
      print('========================================');
      print('Submitting to back end...');
      var contactService = new ContactService();
      contactService.createContact(newContact).then((value) => showMessage(
          'New contact created for ${value.firstName}!', Colors.blue));
    }
  }
}
```

So, when I click the button to navigate to my form page I get the red screen showing the error code I have mentioned above. If it were to work correctly, a sign-up page should appear.

Comment: There is a value that you are passing, that value is null and flutter doesn't expect a null value. You need to identify where in your own code the error occurs.

Comment: Like I said, I'm very new to this, so I don't quite understand how to find exactly where the error is occurring.

Comment: Ok. You got the answer but next time you can scroll through the error output on your terminal. It will show you where the error is in your code. Like this one: _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:sbt/home.dart:74:17)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your title maybe null, which when it goes to the Text widget would cause this error. You can add a default title as follows:

```
MyFormPage({Key key, this.title = ''}) : super(key: key);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This had me stumped for a day or two. It fixed it and it works now. You are a life saver. I upvoted you but my rep is too low for it to show lol.